# Number of irreducible representations of a finite group over a field of characteristic 0

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a field with $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$.

For $K=\mathbb{C}$ the number of irreducible representations of $KG$ is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of $G$.

For $K=\mathbb{R}$ the number of irreducible representations of $KG$ is equal to $\frac{r+s}{2}$, where $r$ denotes the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ and $s$ the number of classes stable under inversion.

For $K=\mathbb{Q}$ the number of irreducible representations of $KG$ is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroups of $G$.

(You can find quick proofs of those results in the very recent book "A Journey Through Representation Theory: From Finite Groups to Quivers via Algebras" by  Caroline Gruson and Vera Serganova, where a nice quick overview of representation theory of finite groups in characteristic 0 is given in chapters 1 and 2.)

Question:

> Are there such nice closed forumlas for other fields $K$? For example quadratic, cubic or cyclotomic field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: To clarify your header, I'd suggest making it longer:  "Number of irreducible representations of a finite group over a field of characteristic 0".     It would also help to give explicit references for $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.   All of this depends on Richard Brauer's results over a splliting field.     See also Chapter 9 of the classic book by I.M. Isaacs *Character Theory of Finite Groups*.   (And as B. Steinberg's answer suggests, the results for a field of characteristic $p>0$ are also fairly explicit.)

Comment: @JimHumphreys Thanks. I followed your suggestions, although I do not know the original articles where this was proven.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a characterization due to Berman for any field. In your case let $n$ be the least common multiple of the orders of elements of $G$. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity. Let $H=Gal(K(\zeta)/K)$. We can identify $H$ with a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*$. Call $a,b\in G$ $K$-conjugate if $b^j=gag^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$ and $j\in H$. This is an equivalence relation and the number of irreducible $KG$-modules is the number of $K$-conjugacy classes.

In characteristic $p$ you do the analogous thing but only look at this equivalence relation on $p$-regular elements.

Comment: Are there convenient references?

Comment: The characteristic 0 case is in Curtis and Reiner. Reiner has a paper maybe in proceedings of the ams doing the modular case with Brauer characters.

Comment: Im traveling now so don't have the books handy.

Comment: In particular, this says that every irrep can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, which is an important consequence (maybe ~equivalent to?) Brauer's induction theorem.

Comment: I believe the induction theorem is used in the proof.